# "Method threw 'java.lang.LinkageError' exception" while calling a stub method

Tags: web-services, soap, axiom, linkageerror

I am trying to call a method of a web service using an auto generated stub.
At following line it assigns,

```
 Method threw 'java.lang.LinkageError' exception. Cannot evaluate org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.soap11.SOAP11BodyImpl.toString()
```

as the SOAP envelope.

```
env = toEnvelope(getFactory(_operationClient.getOptions().getSoapVersionURI()),
                                                simpleQueryInput587,
                                                dummyWrappedType,
                                                optimizeContent(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/bpel4people/ws-humantask/api/200803",
                                                "simpleQuery")));
```

what is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused since same package has been exported by two jars.